# ANT_HOME could not find file for given patterns

Tags: windows, ant

I need help setting ant on windows 7.

Here is my Path variable:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; %JAVA_HOME%; C:\Program
>   Files\ant; C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live; C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live; C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\; C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\iCLS Client\; %SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%;
>   %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\; C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared; C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64; C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL; C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT; C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT; C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;
>   C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
>   C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools; C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;

And here is how my ANT_HOME variable is set:

> C:\ant

Yet it comes up with an error of 'could not find file for given patterns'

The ant folder is definatly set at

> C:\ant

, so I dont know what else to do

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the ant installation folder in C:\apache-ant-1.9.4
Create a new system variable ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.9.4
and add in path  %ANT_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not created a path which is **%ANT_HOME%\bin**

Please follow below steps.

This can be done in 2 different ways:

1: From Command Prompt.

C:>set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5

C:>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

C:>set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:> ant -version

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on July 10 2018

2: By setting environment variables.

Right click on This PC > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > User variables > New > Variable name:**ANT_HOME & for **Variable value:**C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5 > **OK.

Now goto System variables to add bin path. System variables > double click on Path >New > C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin >New >C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin>OK.

Now lets check whether it is installed correctly or not.

goto Command Prompt > and type ant -version.

C:> ant -version

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on July 10 2018

That's it. Let me know if still getting any difficulties.